# I'm trying to perform two string comparisons with an "if" and an "OR"

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and I am trying to do two string comparisons with an or statement. Can anyone give me any idea where I have gone wrong?

```
    echo $DEVICETYPE
    FILEHEADER=ANDROID
    if [[ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPad" ] || ["$DEVICETYPE" == "iPhone" ]];
        then
            $FILEHEADER = IOS
    fi
    echo $FILEHEADER
```

> > > iPad
> > >
> > > ANDROID

Comment: Is `echo $FILEHEADER = IOS` supposed to be an assignment statement? Because it isn't.

Comment: Also you are missing a `]` on the first `[[` test (here: `== "iPad" ] ||`).

Comment: Sorry I added that bit in just to make a fake output to try and explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned I should point this out for completeness. The statement:

```
echo $FILEHEADER = IOS
```

will simply print out the contents of `FILEHEADER` variable followd by `= IOS` . This won't do assignment. Assignment is done as follows with name of variable without the `$` followed by what you wish to assign to it. Note there are no spaces around the `=`. In your example it should have been:

```
FILEHEADER=IOS
```

Regarding the expressions your code:

```
if [[ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPad" ] || ["$DEVICETYPE" == "iPhone" ]];
```

could be replaced with:

```
if [ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPad" ] || [ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPhone" ];
```

You need to remove the outer brackets. As well there is a subtle change that has to be made. You had `["$DEVICETYPE"` you need to add a space after the `[` so it became `[ "$DEVICETYPE"`. If you want to group logical expressions then you could use parentheses so it could have been written this way (although it doesn't change this examples semantics):

```
if ([ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPad" ] || [ "$DEVICETYPE" == "iPhone" ]);
```

If you are only targeting bash then the following may have been the more natural wayto express it. Unfortunately this form may not work in other shells (it is less portable):

```
if [[ $DEVICETYPE == "iPad" || $DEVICETYPE == "iPhone" ]];
```

If you are concerned about operator precedence you could always clarify it with:

```
if [[ ($DEVICETYPE == "iPad") || ($DEVICETYPE == "iPhone") ]];
```

Although not asked but may be of value is to realize that one can use a wildcard asterisk(*) to check for anything that *starts* with iPhone or iPad as in this example:

```
if [[ ($DEVICETYPE == "iPad"*) || ($DEVICETYPE == "iPhone"*) ]];
```

So if `DEVICETYPE` is `iPhone 2` or `iPhone2` or `iPad Mini` then they would all match as well. The asterisk says match any other characters.

Comment: Thanks Michael you've been very helpful :)

Comment: The pattern matching of the last example is bash `[[` specific. Just for the record.

Comment: Yes I pretty much suggested the remainder were less portable. Since this was a bash question I added them. Thanks.